# How to define relative node sizes on Graphviz diagram?

Tags: size, nodes, graphviz

I can't figure out how to set the size of nodes in Graphviz. The `size` parameter only seems to affect the entire chart.

Specifically, I want nodes to scale scale according to some property like the total weight of their children.

**Update:** looks like `fixedsize` might be what I need.

Comment: `height` and `width` also help.

Answer (score 1):

For e.g.

```
digraph G {rankdir="LR"; 
 node [shape=box height=3];
 a -> b
}
```

results in:

[image]